# How to get all possible Doctrine error codes, and description?

Tags: doctrine-orm

How to get all possible Doctrine error codes, and descriptions?

I would like to make own error messages, for each code, but i am not able to find enumerated error codes and descriptions.

If you scroll down, on left menu you will find Dotrine2 Exceptions:
http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/doctrine2.git/
But thye does not have codes. Thus i can not customise error messages.
I need codes listed.

This page lists Doctrine1 Exception codes, but are they valid for Doctrine 2?
http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/doctrine1/class-Doctrine_Connection_Exception.html

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Connection/Exception.php

Comment: http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/doctrine1/class-Doctrine_Connection_Exception.html

Comment: http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/doctrine1/class-Doctrine_Connection_Exception.html

Comment: In doctrine2, i found exception classes in   `vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Exception\`, but they does not contain error codes

Comment: vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php

Comment: Doctrine 2 exceptions : http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/doctrine2.git/

Comment: Most of projects classes and exceptions : http://apigen.juzna.cz/

Comment: But, i could not found clearly listed codes and messages for all errors for Docrtine 2. If somebody has such a list, or knows how to generate it, could you please let me to know.